# setting transparency of static text control

Tags: c#

Is it possible to set transparency of the static text control available in winforms? I tried setting the underlying panels transparency but it is not working for overlapping controls.

Comment: If you mean a label control, set the BackColor property to Transparent.

Comment: I want to control the transparency percentage.

Answer (score 2):

The Label control supports transparency very well.  You get complete transparency by selecting Color.Transparent for the BackColor property.  Partially transparency with a non-zero alpha works well too.  Here's an example with the BackgroundImage property set and a label:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(40, Color.Black);
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Slightly incorrect. You *can* add non-zero alpha in designer too, just enter the component values manually, start with the alpha: i48.tinypic.com/10h95zb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Using a regular `Label` won't help you with true transparency.</strike> I suggest you to draw your string by overriding `OnPaint` or by handling the `Paint` event of the container.

Example:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    var textPosition = new PointF(100, 50);
    using (var font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular))
        e.Graphics.DrawString("My text", font, Brushes.Black, textPosition);
}
```

EDIT: I didn't know that the control actually supported transparency. +1 Hans, leaving the post just for the alternative method.